# DateUtils#truncate() to work in UTC timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, apache-commons-dateutils

I have a java.util.Date on which i am using org.apache.commons.lang.time#truncate(javaUtilDateObj, Calendar.DATE) to convert the date to midnight.

The problem is the UTC date gets represented in local timezone and the truncate method just converts the Hour,minute and seconds to 00:00:00 without considering the timezone.

Example :-
Say UTC time is 30 seconds from epoch. Wed Dec 31 19:00:30 EST 1969 is the Date object representation I am seeing. On calling DateUtils#truncate() method on the above date, the output is Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 EST 1969.

What i am expecting is if UTC time is 30 seconds from epoch. And if that can be represented/converted to Thu Jan 1 00:00:30 EST 1970, i can call DateUtils#truncate() method on that and expect Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 EST 1970.

Note: I am not in a position to use joda-time API and hence I am stuck with what i have.

Comment: FYI, except for UTC, midnight is not always the time `00:00:00.000` because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) and possibly other anomalies. For this reason Joda-Time provides the method `withTimeAtStartOfDay()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar utc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
utc.setTime(date);
Calendar midnight = DateUtils.truncate(utc, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
Date midnightDate = midnight.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) version of [`truncate`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#truncate(java.util.Calendar,%20int)):

```
Calendar utc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).setTime(date);
Calendar midnight = DateUtils.truncate(utc, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
Date midnightDate = midnight.getTime();
```

Comment: setTime() zwraca void a nie Calendar, dodałem poprawne rozwiązanie

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

- Use modern *java.time* classes. Built into Java.
- The day may *not* start at 00:00:00 on some dates in some places.

  - Let *java.time* determine first moment of the day.
- Avoid the ambiguous term “midnight”.

  - Think of “first moment of the day”.
  - Search Stack Overflow to learn about Half-Open spans of time.

First moment of the day:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;    // Specify the region whose wall-clock time you want to perceive “today”. Specify time zone with `Continent/Region`, never the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST`. 
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;          // Capture the current date as seen in a specific time zone.
ZonedDateTime zdt = today.atStartOfDay( z ) ;   // Let java.time determine first moment of the day.
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;             // Adjust from time zone to UTC. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

## Details

Many problems at play here.

## Adjusting zones

> if UTC time is 30 seconds from epoch. And if that can be represented/converted to Thu Jan 1 00:00:30 EST 1970,

No, wrong. You cannot convert. Those two date-time values do *not* represent the same moment. If by `EST` you meant a time zone such as `America/New_York` or `America/Montreal`, then those two values are **several hours apart**.

```
Instant thirtySecondsFromEpoch = Instant.EPOCH.plusSeconds( 30 ) ;
```

> thirtySecondsFromEpoch.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00:30Z

See that same moment in much of the east coast of North America.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtAdjustedFromThirtySecondsFromEpoch = thirtySecondsFromEpoch.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdtAdjustedFromThirtySecondsFromEpoch.toString(): 1969-12-31T19:00:30-05:00[America/New_York]

Because most of the people on the east coast of North America use a wall-clock time that is five hours *behind* UTC, that same moment of 30 seconds past epoch is seen as half a minute past 7 PM the day before, the last day of 1969.

Try the same time-of-day, 30 seconds into the first day of 1970, but as seen in `America/New_York` time zone rather than in UTC. Now we are talking about a different moment entirely. Half a minute into a new day happens **five hours later** than a half a minute into new day in UTC.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 1970 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 30 , 0 , z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00:30-05:00[America/New_York]
>
> zdt.toInstant().toString(): 1970-01-01T05:00:30Z

## Time zone

You ignore the crucial issue of time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

## `java.util.Date::toString`

The `toString` method on `Date` has a well-intentioned but troublesome behavior of implicitly applying the JVM’s current default time zone while generating a string representing the `Date` object’s UTC value. Creates the false impression that this zone is present in the `Date`.

This is one of many reasons to avoid this awful class. Use *java.time* classes instead.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date`.

If you have a `Date` in hand, convert to/from `java.time.Instant` via new methods added to the old class.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Avoid talking about “midnight” as that is an amorphous topic. Instead, focus on the first moment of the day, the start of the day.

Do not assume a day starts at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day may start at another time-of-day such as 01:00:00. Let java.time determine the start of the day.

Determining the start of the day means determining the date. And determining the date requires a time zone, as mentioned above. So we need to adjust from your `Instant` in UTC to a `ZonedDateTime` in a specific time zone (`ZoneId`) .

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract from that `ZonedDateTime` just the date-only portion.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Now ask for the first moment of the day in a specified time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStartOfDay = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

## Truncating

You can truncate various java.time objects. Look for a `truncatedTo` method where you pass a [`TemporalUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html) object (likely a [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html)) to specify the granularity you want in your result. No need for the Apache DateUtils for this purpose.

If truncating `Instant` you are always using UTC for the time zone logic.

```
Instant instantTrucToDay = Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS ) ;
```

More likely, you will want to truncate within the context a some time zone other than UTC as discussed above.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtTruncToDay = zdt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS ) ;
```

By the way, if your ultimate goal is to work with an entire date, a date-only without any time-of-day or zone, just stick to using `LocalDate`.

> if UTC time is 30 seconds from epoch. And if that can be represented/converted to Thu Jan 1 00:00:30 EST 1970

Not sure what you meant here. But keep in mind that given 30 seconds after the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (1970-01-01T00:00:30Z), **the same moment in the east coast of North America is several hours earlier**. That means around 7 PM the previous day.

```
Instant instantThirtySecsAfterEpoch = Instant.EPOCH.plusSeconds( 30 ) ;
```

> instantThirtySecsAfterEpoch.toString(): 1970-01-01T00:00:30Z

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instantThirtySecsAfterEpoch.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 1969-12-31T19:00:30-05:00[America/New_York]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Following function is usefull if your data layer saves UTC times but your presentation layer has different timeZone and you need to truncate a Date for filtering.

```
/**
 * Truncates the given UTC date for the given TimeZone
 *
 * @param date UTC date
 * @param timeZone Target timezone
 * @param field Calendar field
 *
 * @return
 */
public static Date truncate(Date date, final TimeZone timeZone, final int field)
{
    int timeZoneOffset = timeZone.getOffset(date.getTime());

    // convert UTC date to target timeZone
    date = DateUtils.addToDate(date, Calendar.MILLISECOND, timeZoneOffset);

    // truncate in target TimeZone
    date = org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.truncate(date, field);

    // convert back to UTC
    date = DateUtils.addToDate(date, Calendar.MILLISECOND, -timeZoneOffset);

    return date;
}

/**
 * Adds the given amount to the given Calendar field to the given date.
 *
 * @see Calendar
 *
 * @param date the date
 * @param field the calendar field to add to
 * @param amount the amount to add, may be negative
 *
 * @return
 */
public static Date addToDate(final Date date, final int field, final int amount)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(date, "date must not be null");

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.add(field, amount);
    return c.getTime();
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).